# Accessing the fan under Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows, io, hardware

I tried to compile the sample "DumbPort" from WinIO on a 64-Bit Windows 7 OS but when I run the program I always get this error insufficient user rights. I've put the winIO64.dll and winIO64.sys in the same directory like DumbPort. In the source code of the sample the error message is not very helpful because it means that the WinIo library is found but it cannot be initialized. I'm using Visual Studio 8 and I'm not sure how I can debug this. Here is the code:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Check if this is a 32 bit or 64 bit system
        if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
        {
            hMod = LoadLibrary("WinIo32.dll");

        }
        else if (IntPtr.Size == 8)
        {
            hMod = LoadLibrary("WinIo64.dll");
        }

        if (hMod == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can't find WinIo dll.\nMake sure the WinIo library files are located in the same directory as your executable file.", "DumpPort", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            this.Close();
        }

        IntPtr pFunc = GetProcAddress(hMod, "InitializeWinIo");

        if (pFunc != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            InitializeWinIoType InitializeWinIo = (InitializeWinIoType)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pFunc, typeof(InitializeWinIoType));
            bool Result = InitializeWinIo();

            if (!Result)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error returned from InitializeWinIo.\nMake sure you are running with administrative privileges and that the WinIo library files are located in the same directory as your executable file.", "DumpPort", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                FreeLibrary(hMod);
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: You are running under elevated permissions?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Windows Home 7.

Comment: In the past I have just use WinRing0 with great success. Again it all depends on the chip on the motherboard with what you can do. Probably like my case, lotsa reverse engineering.

Comment: That guy needs funding and the download link is broken: http://www.winring0.com-about.com/download.html.

Comment: But I know where I can get it. Any other idea?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/winring0/

Comment: I can make it work with NHC (http://www.pbus-167.com/nhc/nhc.htm) but I'm unsure know. I want to make a simple  Systray Windows 7 application to control the fan.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/winring0/ doesn't work the archive is empty. Is this project dead?

Comment: I see what you mean, sorry. I will try find a copy, or upload it for you. In the meanwhile, try http://openhardwaremonitor.org/ it might support your system already. Else ask the developer to add support (he is a friendly chap).

Comment: Here is the code http://www.koders.com/info.aspx?c=ProjectInfo&pid=85MHDKAXNVXQBWCD2X6LCTQ9HH&s=textbox but I can't make it work. Do you have a sample code to include winring0.dll?

Comment: leppie: here is what I've done http://www.chihoang.de/code-schnipsel/amilo-xa-3530/fsc-xa-3530-fan-control-v01-windows.html but I also wrote a kernel module and a systray app. I like it more!

Comment: +1 Cool. Interesting stuff, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. not bad. it's similar to Linux Kernel but I've to learn Windows tools and nameing a lot. It makes me feel a bit lost. Openhardwaremonitor didn't support my device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I've solved my problem with winring0: http://www.chihoang.de/code-schnipsel/amilo-xa-3530/fsc-xa-3530-fan-control-v01-windows.html. Currently I'm trying to write a kernel driver and a systray program to control it.